# Syntax Help - variable reference within variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below foreach loop

```
$i = 1;
    $array = array();
    foreach ($titles as $title){
        if (empty($title) ){
            echo "EMPTY " .$i ;
        }else{
            array_push($array, $_POST['miles'.$i.'1']);
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

The line `array_push($array, $_POST['miles'.$i.'1']);` should add to the array the value of `$_POST['miles11']` on the first loop (so long as $title is not empty).

And then on the next loop value of `$_POST['miles21']` etc. etc.

However this does not work as nothing actually gets added to the array just an empty item.
I assume I do not have the syntax right for doing the above but I am not sure what is the correct way to do it.

Thank you

Examples

If all $titles are not empty the array looks like:

```
 Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => )
```

If some are empty we get for example:

```
EMPTY 1EMPTY 3EMPTY 5EMPTY 7Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )
```

Comment: And you are sure that `$title` is not empty?

Comment: Yes very sure sorry should have included the output example

Comment: `var_dump($titles)` + `var_dump($_POST)`. Then you will find your answer

Comment: And do you know that the various `$_POST['miles'.$i.'1']` have values?

Comment: tried `$array[]=$_POST['miles'.$i.'1']` instead og array_push??

Comment: Yes, you should include the output example

Comment: So it always adds null to the array. Please show us your `$_POST` array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_push($array, $_POST['miles'.$i.'1']);
```

actually needs to be

```
array_push($array, $_POST['miles1'.$i]);
```

after looking at my $_POST again

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
$data['miles21'] = 'aku';
$titles= array(0=>'1',1=>'2',3=>'3',4=>'4',5=>'5',6=>'6');
$array = array();
foreach ($titles as $title){
    if (empty($title) ){
        echo "EMPTY " .$i ;
    }else{
        array_push($array, $data['miles'.$i.'1']);
    }
    var_dump($data['miles'.$i.'1']);
    $i++;
}
var_dump($array);
```

I try this code, the data $array will have data "aku" in index 1...

double check with var_dump($title), var_dump($_POST['miles'.$i.'1']), etc...